# Rails table_name_prefix missing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, module, prefix

I have got the following dir structure

```
models/foo/setting.rb
models/foo.rb
```

foo.rb content

```
 module Foo
  def self.table_name_prefix
    'foo_'
  end
 end
```

and setting.rb content

```
class Foo::Setting < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

As soon as I am calling `Foo::Setting.find…` I am getting an error `SQLException: no such table: settings` which is indeed correct because the table is named `foo_settings` so rails seems to ignore the table prefix specified for the module Foo.

What can I do so that rails considers the prefix?

Comment: Which version of Rails are you using?

Comment: As Qerub mentioned, you should check your Rails version, because if im not mistaken, this feature came in from 3.0

Comment: Did some experimenting. It works if I do a `require 'repsys.rb'` in `models/foo/setting.rb`. Seems like Rails doesn't load `foo.rb`if I am accessing `Foo::Settings`. If requiring is the only solution that would be pretty poor!

Comment: I already have some code working correctly in my app, but now I get this error with another namespace. Using rails 3.2.6.

Comment: Thanks for the question. Running into the same problem, but only when I run it on heroku, locally it all works fine. I can live with your workaround for now. Did you ever find a better solution?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You've define a method inside a module (Foo). This doesn't magically define that method on a class nested in that module.

I'd try something like

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
  self.table_name_prefix = 'foo_'
end
```

And then inherit from `Foo`

```
class Foo::Setting < Foo
...
end
```

Comment: Rails generated that module and the structure. Are you sure? If so `rails generate` will generate something that is not runnable.

Comment: It generates something that's runnable, just not something that does what you want. If you're just namespacing your models then all you need is a mode

Comment: Spree commerce seem to be using this method also.. https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/master/core/app/models/spree.rb
But I cant figure out how they've done it

Comment: I don't think this answer is correct. For some of my models it does magically define that method on the nested classes but for others it doesn't?

Comment: Sounds like you should ask a fresh question, showing when it works and when it doesn't - there's not really room in comments to do all that

Comment: wrong, according to [the docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/table_name_prefix/class) for `table_name_prefix`, the OP code should work. My guess is that it has to do with the autoloader (see my answer). Your answer is still working though, so no downvote ;)

Comment: ah, yes active record rather than calling just table_name_prefix tries to walk up the module chain calling table_name_prefix all the way

Comment: the answer below by @m_x is much superior, as it identifies the core of the problem.

Comment: It is important to note, that if table_name is overrided, table_name_prefix doesn't work https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29174840/activerecord-ignores-table-name-prefix

Answer (score 11):

This is probably caused by rails' autoloader. When doing this :

```
module Foo
  class Bar
  end
end
```

And then trying to use `Foo::Bar`, the autoloader first tries to locate `app/models/foo/bar.rb`. The file is loaded, and `module Foo` is defined here (albeit as a module containing solely `Bar`) so the autoloader never attempts to load `app/models/foo.rb`.

This should only happen in development mode, as in production mode all of your files are `require`'d on startup.

There are two workarounds AFAIK :

**Cheat the autoloader**

declare your class using `class Foo::Bar`, to force the autoloader to resolve a constant lookup for `Foo`.

This has the annoying side effect that the constant lookup inside `Bar` will NOT be scoped inside `Foo`, for instance :

```
# app/models/foo.rb
module Foo
 BAZ = "baz"
end

# app/models/foo/bar.rb
class Foo::Bar
  def baz
    BAZ
  end
end
```

here, `Foo::Bar.new.baz`will fail, unless you reference the constant using `Foo::BAZ`. This can get really a mess when defining ActiveRecord associations, for instance.

**Require the module**

using `require_dependency` :

```
require_dependency 'foo'
module Foo
  class Bar
  end
end
```

This is IMHO the right solution, as it does not break the constant lookup, but it is also a bit annoying as you have to add the require statement on top of each namespaced file.

**Note :**

This bug seems to have been resolved in rails 4. I used the second workaround a lot while on rails 3, but I've tried to reproduce the bug in rails 4 and it does not show up anymore. I think they modified the way the autoloader works... For more info, see [the rails guides on autoloading and reloading constants](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html#resolution-algorithms)

Comment: Under some cases I have this bug too

Comment: i still had this bug intermittently show up on a CI run at work with rails 4.  so we didn't have to require_dependency we required the module in an initializer.  i prefer this way as opposed to needing to require_dependancy because that means any other dev that comes along will need to remember to require dependancy as well.

Comment: Yup, I've still had this crop up in an application in Rails 4 and 5. We deal with it by creating a base model as described in the other answer, but `require_dependency` would work fine too. Kinda frustrating that the Rails generator gives you an unreliable default scheme for this.

Answer (score 2):

Just create a base class in inside your namespaced model directory and require Foo in it, then extend your models from the base class.

Say I have `app/models/foo.rb`

```
module Foo
  def self.table_name_prefix
    'tble_prefix_'
  end
end
```

Then in `app/models/foo/base_record.rb`

```
require_dependency 'foo'
module Foo
  class BaseRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.abstract_class = true
  end
end
```

Then extend from the `BaseRecord`

```
module Foo
  class Bar < BaseRecord

  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Solved it by changing either of my application's namespace or the model's.

Take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11930418/ruby-on-rails-model-not-following-namespace-updated/20359588). Using the same namespace for the application as for models causes to models not pick up the parent namespace table_name_prefix correctly.