# Rspec + Rails: table_name_prefix not loaded for module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

When I run rspec on a specific file:

`rspec spec/models/my_namespace/my_model_spec.rb`

I run into an error because rspec appears not to load app/models/my_namespace.rb, which contains the declaration of `self.table_name_prefix`. In fact, if I use pry and run ``` MyNamepsace.table_name_prefix # => NoMethodError: undefined method ``table_name_prefix' ```.

When I try to query the db from Rails console (no rspec), it works, though: `MyNamespace::MyModel.where(foo:'bar') # => [...]`

Any idea what the problem or fix is?

*Rails 3.2.14, Ruby 1.9.3, Debian*

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails table\_name\_prefix missing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8911046/rails-table-name-prefix-missing)

Comment: Thanks for the link to the other question, but the answer there doesn't really satisfy, and the question does not discriminate between rspec-testing and actually running the rails application. When it is run in an ordinary rails console (not rspec), the table_name is produced correctly, including the prefix.

Comment: besides which, the contention and the answer on that thread is that the static method on the module (Foo) is in no way linked to the model (Setting), but that's not the problem in my case; in my case,  the module file appears not even to be loading because `table_name_prefix `appears not even to be defined on the module.

Comment: Have you included the rspec-rails gem? Are you requiring `spec_helper`?

Answer (score 1):

At the top of your spec file:

```
require_relative '../../../app/models/my_namespace'
```

This will load the namespace file which specifies the table prefix.