# ActiveRecord ignores table_name_prefix

Tags: ruby, activerecord

I've got situation where I need to define table_name and table_name_prefix within a model and for some reason table_name overrides table_name_prefix.

```
class ScheduleItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = "schedule_item"
  self.table_name_prefix = 'ACQ_IBM_T.'
end
```

The prefix is completely ignored in the queries. But, when I comment out the table_name part then the prefix is added. Anyone has seen strange behavior like this before?

Answer (score 4):

In [ActiveRecord::ModelSchema::ClassMethods](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb), the `table_name` setter puts the value in `@table_name`:

```
def table_name=(value)
  ...
  @table_name        = value
```

And the `table_name` getter just uses the `@table_name` value if it is defined:

```
def table_name
  reset_table_name unless defined?(@table_name)
  @table_name
end
```

The `table_name_prefix` is only used to help Rails when it is trying to guess the table name based on the class name (in `reset_table_name`).

If you have a table name that Rails can't guess, you can do this:

```
class ScheduleItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = "ACQ_IBM_T.schedule_item"
```

Or if you need to use the prefix somewhere else, you can do this:

```
class ScheduleItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name_prefix = 'ACQ_IBM_T.'
  self.table_name = "#{table_name_prefix}schedule_item"
```