# Cannot load Ruby Model under a namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a namespaced Post controller as below

```
class Admin::Blog::PostsController < Admin::BaseController
end
```

and a namespaced model as follows.

```
class Blog::Post < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

But when I try to access the model inside the index action of the post controller as below

```
def index
    @posts = Blog::Post.where(:foo_id => params[:id]).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 20)
  end
```

I get the following error

```
LoadError at /admin/blog/posts

Expected/app/models/blog/post.rb to define Post
```

But when I move the model to Admin::Blog::Post namespace from Blog::Post is works.

I'm bit confused with this and not able to get what is going on with this.
Is it required that Controller and Model should be present in the same namespace ?

Following is the snippet from routes.rb

```
namespace :admin do
    namespace :blog do
        resources :posts
        resources :categories
    end
end
```

Blog module snippet

```
module Blog
  def self.table_name_prefix
    'blog_'
  end
end
```

Preloading controllers and models

```
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{Rails.root}/app/models/**/**"]
    config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{Rails.root}/app/controllers/**/**"]
    config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/app/helpers/**/**"]
    config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/app/tags/**/**"]
    config.autoload_paths += %W[ #{Rails.root}/app/extensions #{Rails.root}/app/modules #{Rails.root}/app/drops #{Rails.root}/app/filters  #{Rails.root}/app/mailers ]
```

Comment: Can you add the snippet related to Blog posts from the routes.rb as well...

Comment: @VamsiKrishna I have added routes.rb snippet.

Comment: So blog is not a model in your case

Comment: Yes it is not a model, it is just an module with the snippet shown above.

Comment: rails expects name spacing to also be reflected in the directory tree. Where are these files located?

Comment: Does this work?: `@posts = ::Blog::Post.where`

Comment: @engineersmnky those files are located under the proper directory structure
app/controllers/admin/blog/posts_controller.rb &
app/models/blog/post.rb

Comment: @zetetic I tried that but din't work for me.

Comment: @VamsiKrishna yes I'm trying that now.

Comment: @VamsiKrishna I tried your answer but sorry it din't work, it gives same error.

Comment: Did you change the resources :posts to :blog_posts and remember to restart the server for the changes to take effect.

Comment: @VamsiKrishna yes i tried that but now it is expecting the controller to be 


ActionController::RoutingError at /admin/blog_posts

uninitialized constant Admin::BlogPostsController

And what I have is Admin::Blog::PostsControlle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably caused by rails' autoloader. When doing this :

```
module Foo
  class Bar
  end
end
```

And then trying to use `Foo::Bar`, the autoloader first tries to locate `app/models/foo/bar.rb`. The file is loaded, and `module Foo` is defined here (albeit as a module containing solely `Bar`) so the autoloader never attempts to load `app/models/foo.rb`.

This should only happen in development mode, as in production mode all of your files are `require`'d on startup.

There are two workarounds AFAIK :

**Require the module**

using `require_dependency` :

```
require_dependency 'foo'
module Foo
  class Bar
  end
end
```

This is IMHO the right solution, as it does not break the constant lookup, but it is also a bit annoying as you have to add the require statement on top of each namespaced file.

**Create Custom Active record Base**

This solution doesn't rely on autoloading. Set the models to inherit from the following, instead of from `ActiveRecord::Base` directly:

```
class CustomActiveRecordBase < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true

  # If no table name prefix has been defined, include the namespace/module as
  # table name prefix, e.g., Blog:: -> blog_
  def self.table_name
    # If a table_name_prefix has been defined, follow default behaviour
    return super if full_table_name_prefix.present?

    # Find the prefix, e.g., Blog::Post -> 'blog', User -> ''
    prefix = model_name.name.deconstantize.underscore

    # If no prefix, follow default behaviour
    return super unless prefix.present?

    # Otherwise add the prefix with an underscore
    "#{prefix}_#{super}"
  end
end
```

Then there is no need to define `self.table_name_prefix` in `blog.rb`.

This *could* all be done by monkey-patching `ActiveRecord::Base`, but this interferes with other classes, such as `ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration`, which doesn't have a table prefix.

**Note :**

This bug seems to have been resolved in rails 4. I used the second workaround a lot while on rails 3, but I've tried to reproduce the bug in rails 4 and it does not show up anymore. I think they modified the way the autoloader works... For more info, see [the rails guides on autoloading and reloading constants](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html#resolution-algorithms)

Comment: Yes I checked that but no luck.
May I know like why is it expecting for model Post at "/app/models/blog/post.rb" instead of Blog::Post.

I tried to create a new rails 4.1 app and there I just tried the same thing what I have done here, but it worked over there.
Does preloading all the classes like in my post above affects it ?

Comment: Yes same error
Expected/app/models/blog/post.rb to define Post.

Comment: Check this question and look for tha answer given by m_x in this. Not the accepted answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8911046/rails-table-name-prefix-missing

Comment: Thanks a lot Vamsi, require_dependency worked for me.
Sorry I had upvoted your answer but it will be visible only after me gaining minimum 15 reputation.

Also I wanted to know if using "require_dependency" has any disadvantage other than including it in every namespaced class (in terms of performance or rails autoloading) ?

Comment: I think you should be able to accept the answer though. I don't see any performance issue regarding the same.